# jquery change color when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors

I need to make the code so that once I click on one of the glyphs on the side of the page, elements with id's beginning with the same letter will remain black while everything else, including the other glyphs, turn grey.

This is what I have now and it says 'unexpected identifier' when inspected and I am not quite sure how to fix this and not sure how to proceed to make the other elements go grey.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#A").click(function() {
      $("#apartment", "#apple", "#art-folder", "#air-conditioner").css('"color", "black"');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Just use [startWith](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

Comment: And istead of changing CSS directly just change a class.

Comment: `$("#apartment", "#apple", "#art-folder", "#air-conditioner")` is not how you do multiple element selectors

Comment: `'"color", "black"'`is not the way to parse different parameters either. Get rid of the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [startWith selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$("#A").click(function(){
   $("[id^='A']").css("color", "black");
});
```